# assistance with .getJSON only partially working

Tags: jquery

trying to get some jquery working in my app.  using .getJSON to go to endpoint and get some data...seems to be going to endpoint and getting data but not doing all i want, i am thinking i do not have my getJSON written properly... here is my code:

```
$.getJSON("deliverMlabsJson", function(result){
      
        console.log(result)
        p = result
        g2 = p['0']
        for (var key in p) {
            if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(key + " -> " + 'gman33 ' + p[key].name);
            }
        }
},
function(data,status,xhr) {
    console.log('status = ',status)

}
);
```

1. endpoint seems to be fine since the console log of 'result'shows the json i have the endpoint to output
2. furthermore - the console.log of the items with 'gman33' all show what they should show.ty..
3. so looks like it is getting data back ok
4. problem 1:  I cannot store the data received to be used outside of this jquery function; i have tried a number of things to achieve this
5. the var of g2 - i was trying to save it
6. now all of this decribed so far is in the second property of getJSON
7. problem 2: I cannot get the third property of get JSON to work at all - that is where you can have data, status and xhr..
8. you can see my attempt at that but my console log does not show up...

So I am really hoping someone can help me with one or both of these problems.  Thanks!

Comment: Problem 1: You're likely trying to use your data before you received it. You need a mechanism in your jquery function to dispatch whatever methods you want to use after getting the data. Also: Try using the "jqXHR Object" notation, see if it helps your other problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input Slava… You were helpful in that you caused me to learn more about something I am very weak in.  I have been doing a lot of reading on this and some testing and come to realize some things (which just happen  to be the same things you were saying.)  My getJson is probably working fine for the most part.  It is ‘async’ which means it starts but code but my app will keep executing code after the getJson even before it completes.  So we get the situation where I am trying to log the result before it exists.

Comment: The next question is ‘what to do about it?”   I understand to some extent what is needed.  To accommodate this async portion will have to restructure the rest of the app…. Will be working on it…. Thanks….

Comment: As a side note, jquery isnt used much nowadays. For fetching json, take a look at the *fetch API* on MDN.

Comment: yeah - our 'rockstar' developer brian is all about 'react', and views jquery as old school; i have done a little react and it is very cool; but on your comment, I believe i did try the 'fetch' thing in all the testing i did, cant remember if i got it to work or not, tried all kinds of thtings... anyway - will be working on how to make the whole thing work with an async pull, there are always tons of ways to do things...some better and some worse...